# Salesforce trigger to delete attachment

Tags: triggers, salesforce

I'm trying to delete an attachment from a case after the case is closed. The trigger should only fire when a custom check box on the case object is checked.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Similar to this question on Salesforce StackExchange. In your case, Attachment is the child record: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45566/deleting-child-records-on-a-parent

Answer (score 0):

You can write an After Update trigger on the Case object, and check inside the trigger the two conditions (Case.isclosed and CustomCheck = true ), then query on the attachments whose parentid match with the id of this case. Then Database.delete the attachment list which you queried above. Hope this helps !

EDIT : Ofcourse you must bulkify your triggers as a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

In trigger you should get id records who have selected check box.

When you have id's yours records run query like this:
`SELECT Id ParentId FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId in: youIdList`
and delete result of query.